# Re-enable Network Manager?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I started doing Ubuntu literally a day or so ago. To get a certain USB NIC to work, I had to disable the Network Manager; the readme stated that the Network Manager would interfere with the Command Line. I have a new card that I believe will work, but I'd like to know how to re-enable Network Manager, based on the commands I used to turn it off in the first place, which I found on another help forum.

```
sudo stop network-manager
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

So. What command do I use to re-enable network-manager? A step-by-step would be nice... I'm something of a noob when it comes to this stuff...

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 3):

As long as `/etc/init/network-manager.override` [contains `manual`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files), Network Manager will not start automatically when you boot, you will have to do:

```
sudo service network-manager start # or restart
```

To re-enable automatic start for Network Manager, remove that file:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following commands:

sudo service network-manager stop

sudo service network-manager start